# LoaderException when calling CodeDom based code generation from inside IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython, codedom

I have a piece of code which uses CodeDom to generate code on the fly. It's straight forward:

- `CodeCompileUnit` is created and filled with a type.
- The unit is passed to `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom`.
- The assembly is generated in memory and everything is wrapped inside a single static method, which returns an instance of the generated type.

If I call this static method from C#, everything works fine, but it fails if I call the method from IronPython. There are no compile errors and `CompiledAssembly` of the returned `CompilerResults` is NOT null. But if I call `GetTypes` for the assembly, I get a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` which tells me to look at the LoaderExceptions. That one is a `FileNotfoundException` giving the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PosData, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.":"PosData, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

PosData is my own assembly which holds the code generation stuff and which is already loaded by IronPython. Everything is in a single folder, so I don't see what might be missing.

Any hint would be very appreciated!

Comment: This is difficult to investigate without having a project that reproduces the problem. You could for example compare the IL generated from your calling C# and IronPyton code to see whether there are differences.

Comment: I also had the FileNotfoundException on GetTypes before when the assembly was already loaded. The problem was that an assembly referenced by the loaded assembly was not found.

Comment: You should definitely post some IronPython code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the Fusion Log Viewer a shot to get more information about what's going.

See Scott Hanselman's [blog entry](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN for details on how to use it.